# Find similarity between 2 sample data points using Random Forest Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

Let’s assume that you trained a Random Forest model with 10 estimators on a dataset and passed 2 sample data points (S1 and S2) through each of the trees in the forest. You get to see the leaf node indices that correspond to each data point.

```
S1 = [5,4,1,7,8,2,5,6,1,2]

S2 = [4,5,1,7,9,1,7,6,3,2]
```

Note: The leaf node indices shown above are not one-hot encoded and correspond to the leaf node number in each tree.

I calculated the similarity between two sample data points by finding the common leaf indices and dividing them by total number of estimators so am getting 0.4.

Is this the right correct approach to solve the underlying problem?

Comment: It's an interesting approach but usually similarity between data points is calculated on the instances themselves, not the leaf nodes after prediction. What is exactly the "underlying problem" that you try to solve?

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification it is basically an a homework problem only the above information was given

Comment: ok in this case without the original instances that would be the only way indeed

Comment: @Erwan Thanks for the clarification